# Change the color of tax price in the cart page in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax

I am trying to change the colour and size of the VAT cost in the cart and checkout in my woocommerce. I only want to change how the VAT looks and not the total amount.

I am using that css:

```
.woocommerce-page .cart-collaterals .cart_totals table th:last-child {
    colour:#000000;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

any ideas?

Comment: Show the HTML..

Comment: can you  please provide the structure of the DOM so we can properly style them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to use **`color`** instead of `colour`.

You should try this css:

```css
.woocommerce-page #content .cart-collaterals .cart_totals>table tr.total .includes_tax .amount {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

This should work.